# Record reader that can split by two kinds of separators

Tags: java, apache-pig, user-defined-functions

I have a case where I need to read files with lines of the format

```
Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6#Field1,Field2,Field3
```

While one way to achive this would be to use a record reader like `KeyValueLineRecordReader` with the separator `#`. But I will have to split the key and value on `,` in my UDF using `String.split` which I feel can slow down the execution.
 1. Are there any record readers that serve formats of this type?
 2. If one such a record writer doesn't exist, what are my alternatives for reading such a line efficiently?

Input data is ~10GB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in the split

```
String line = "Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6#Field1,Field2,Field3";

String arr [] = line.split(",|#");

for (String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: My input data is around 10GB. While split is something I'm currently using, I feel it's brute force way to deal with it. (nothing to back it up rather an intuition).

Comment: Well you could just go for a traditional loop testing each char individually - sounds slower though

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged the question with apache-pig,I'll give a PIG solution.Load the record into 1 field,replace # with ',' and then use [STRSPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#strsplit) to get the individual fields.No need for java or any UDF.

```
A = LOAD 'input.txt' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT(REPLACE(line,'#',','),',',9);
DUMP B;
```